# How to make Line graph using csv file. with 4 columns. and the year is by decade

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm a newbie and wanna do a line graph.
I wanna do a line graph of decades on the x axis and # of religion on the y-axis but two lines, one religious schools, and one non-religious.

here is my csv file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16XuvoQKSrSMaUPsfHOWY6cBy1ry6UNz6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The csv link gives me a "you need access" error. Could you edit some example data directly into your question (as text, not images), as well as the code that you've tried so far?

Comment: I've edited the file.

Comment: i tried inserting the code. but i keep getting error and cant upload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('ReligiousRate.csv', dtype='string')

df_religious = df[['Religious', 'founded1']]
df_non_religious = df[['Non-Religious', 'founded2']]

dfs = [df_religious, df_non_religious]
names = ['Religious Schools', 'Non Religious Schools']

counts = []
for df, name in zip(dfs, names):
    df.columns = ['Name', 'Founded']
    df['Founded'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Founded'], yearfirst=True)
    df = df.set_index('Founded')
    df_decades = df.resample('10AS').count()
    df_decades.columns = [name]
    counts.append(df_decades)

sns.set_palette(["#090364", "#ff0000"])
sns.lineplot(data=pd.concat(counts), dashes=False)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Graph Output]

Comment: Glad to help! If you feel like this has sufficiently answered your question, please mark this answer as the accepted answer :)